# Can´t run acceleo uml2java example

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

I´m beginning with Acceleo.

I installed eclipse-modeling-luna-M6-win32.
Then i installed acceleo by update on eclipse.
(is there any better option?)

Trying to use the uml2java example.
To run it i tried to run org.eclipse.acceleo.examples.uml2java.

It gave me:

Error
Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.examples.uml2java.main.Uml2java from project org.eclipse.acceleo.examples.uml2java
Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.examples.uml2java.main.Uml2java. Check that its containing package is exported.

I did not change the code.
I checked the MANIFEST and it has on the runtime: org.eclipse.acceleo.examples.uml2java.main

I also saw that there is an UI project that as i understand is a plugin but i don´t know what to do with it (so that it will create a new menu on eclipse).

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: it worked using eclipse indigo with the latest acceleo. i don´t know if it´s possible to use a more recent eclipse version.

Comment: also works with eclipse kepler..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked using eclipse indigo with the latest acceleo. i don´t know if it´s possible to use a more recent eclipse version.  also works with eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me. Try adding the "bin/" directory to the Classpath in the Manifest file.

Right click the MANIFEST.MF file and "Open With >" "Plug-in Manifest Editor".

This gives some tabs at the bottom. Use the "Runtime" tab. On the bottom right of this screen there is a place to edit the classpath. Add "bin/".

I got this idea from Etienne's answer in: [Can't generate java from UML using Acceleo in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161250/cant-generate-java-from-uml-using-acceleo-in-eclipse)