# Acceleo code-generation doesn't start, Couldn't load main class

Tags: acceleo

I created a new very easy Acceleo project, with just one main module *generate.mtl* that tries to create a new file. The package is exported in the Manifest. When I launch the .mtl file, I get this error

```
!MESSAGE Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample.main.Generate. Check that its containing package is exported.

!MESSAGE Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample.main.Generate from project org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample
```

I don't really know why and what to do.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding the bin directory to the classpath in the Manifest file.

I did this because of Etienne's answer here: Can't generate java from UML using Acceleo in Eclipse[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161250/cant-generate-java-from-uml-using-acceleo-in-eclipse)

When you open up the MANIFEST.MF with the "Plugin Manifest Editor", there is a "Runtime" tab at the bottom. On the right side bottom of that screen there is a place to edit the classpath. I added "bin/"

After that, I had no problems with loading the class.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the version 3.4 of Acceleo, instead of the 3.5.  The 3.4 works

Answer (score 0):

Your solution @jpcahoon - Solved my problem with Acceleo 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today despite having the *Classpath* declared in the *Manifest* file. 
The solution for me was to tweak the *Execution Environment* in the *Overview* tab of the manifest file (In my case, setting it to JavaSE-1.6 solved the problem).